# How do I convert c types to python integers without having it declared? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Ugh, another programming question guys, haha.

So anyways, I became pretty interested in ctypes with python.
ctypes basically allows you to call c variables within python (Awesome, I know)
so here is how you declare variables with ctypes now:

```
import ctypes as c
class test(c.Structure):
   _fields_ = [
               ("example" , c.c_long),
               ...
              ]
```

Here's the thing though, whenever I use string formatting:

```
    print("test: %d" % (test.example)
```

it tells me that I needs it to be a Python Integer, not a C long.

Here's where it becomes complicated, because example isn't really declared, I can't do a .value method. It will return a syntax error. I can't declare example as a python integer because there is no way to do that. (at least, as far as I know)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a class; create an instance of `test` instead:

```
import ctypes as c

class test(c.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("example" , c.c_long)]

t = test(5)
print(t.example) # -> 5
print("%d" % t.example) # -> 5
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I'm a bit of a n00b however, could you please explain what t = test(5) is doing? But this answer helps! thank you!

Comment: @NortonPenguinion: if you have a class `C` in Python then to create an instance of that class, you just call it with appropriate arguments `C(*args, **kwargs)`.