# Python: kernel32.CreateProcessA() What is it doing?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am currently learning about debuggers and how they stop processes.

Here is my code:

```
    from ctypes import *
    WORD = c_ushort
    DWORD = c_ulong
    LPBYTE = POINTER(c_ubyte)
    LPTSTR = POINTER(c_char)
    HANDLE = c_void_p
    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010
    class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("cb", DWORD),
        ("lpReserved", LPTSTR),
        ("lpDesktop", LPTSTR),
        ("lpTitle", LPTSTR),
        ("dwX", DWORD),
        ("dwY", DWORD),
        ("dwXSize", DWORD),
        ("dwYSize", DWORD),
        ("dwXCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwYCountChars", DWORD),
        ("dwFillAttribute",DWORD),
        ("dwFlags", DWORD),
        ("wShowWindow", WORD),
        ("cbReserved2", WORD),
        ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
        ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
        ("hStdError", HANDLE),
        ]
    class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("hProcess", HANDLE),
        ("hThread", HANDLE),
        ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
        ("dwThreadId", DWORD),
        ]


    kernel32 = windll.kernel32
    class debugger():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def load(path_to_exe):
            creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
            startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
            processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
            startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
            startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0
            startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
            if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,None,None,None,None,creation_flags,None,None,byref(startupinfo),byref(processinfo)):
                print("[*] Process launched")
                print("[*] PID: %d" % (PROCESS_INFORMATION.dwProcessId))
            else:
                print("[*] Error: 0x%08x." % (kernel32.GetLastError()))

    debugger.load("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe")
```

Whenever I run it, it goes to the error. :( I figured out that the reason that it is going to that error is because the kernel32.CreateProcessA is returning false. I'm actually following along Gray hat python right now, and I'm converting this code to python 3 as I read it.

My question is, what is the kernel32.CreateProcessA doing, why is it returning false, and how can I prevent it from returning false?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try to pass a bytestring: `debugger.load(b"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe")` on Python 3

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Thanks again Sebastian, but this brings up another error: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not _ctypes.CField How would you solve that one? I'm really new to this win32api stuff. I appreciate your help so much man!

Comment: Use `processinfo.dwProcessId` instead of `PROCESS_INFORMATION.dwProcessId` [(I've already answered it in your previous question)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15151379/4279). The main purpose of `ctypes` is to allow to call C functions from pure Python. It implies that to use it successfully you should know both C and Python. It might be simpler to learn one language at a time.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help, I'm sorry if I ever sound silly, however I'm still pretty new to this. Thanks for your contribution. I couldn't have done this without you.

Comment: You should also post the error from the kernel. (eg. the output of `print("[*] Error: 0x%08x." % (kernel32.GetLastError()))`)
Because it's hard to tell without it what went wrong as your code appears to be okay.

Answer (score 5):

You have several error in your code:

The first error is `load` method of `debugger` class defined wrong. The most probably in your case it should be staticmethod:

```
# . . .

# This decorator required to make method static
@staticmethod
def load(path_to_exe):
    creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
    startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
    startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1

# . . .
```

The second error is at `print` if process was created:

```
if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,None,None,None,None,
                           creation_flags,None,None,
                           byref(startupinfo),byref(processinfo)):
    print("[*] Process launched")

    # ERROR AT THE LINE BELOW
    # Your variant: print("[*] PID: %d" % (PROCESS_INFORMATION.dwProcessId))
    # But it should be the structure itself not it "type"
    print("[*] PID: %d" % (processinfo.dwProcessId))  
else:
    print("[*] Error: 0x%08x." % (kernel32.GetLastError()))
```

In my case it's works (Windows XP). If your process not really started and you get in console message something like that:

```
[*] Error: 0x00000002
```

Then if you use Python 3.x you should use not `CreateProcessA` but `CreateProcessW` function because all string in Python 3.x is in unicode (in WinAPI all functions ends with 'A' accept asci-strings, ends with 'W' accept unicode-strings). More exactly answer can be if you write what error or exception occurred in your case.

Answer (score 4):

I have a problm when I run a program like you on win64.But when I changed kernel32.CreateProcessA to kernel32.CreateProcessW,the program run sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your first two parameters so you have something like:

```
kernel32.CreateProcessA(c_char_p(0),c_char_p(path_to_exe),0,0,0,creation_flags,0,0,bytef(startupinfo),byref(processinfo))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call **GetLastError** function to know what the error really is.

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError

And I found this detailed post explaining how to debugg and fix error caused by CreateProcessA: [Python CreateProcessA returns FALSE](http://redino.net/blog/2013/07/python-createprocessa-returns-0/)

Answer (score 0):

1. this line must be brackets: 
     debugger().load("C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe")
2. this line must be contain self: 
     def load(self,path_to_exe)
3. if static must not contain self : 
     @staticmethod
     def load(path_to_exe)
4. this line must be: print("[*] PID: %d" % processinfo.dwProcessId)

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [a quick sum-up of differences between Python 2xx vs 3xx](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html) :
   Python 2 has separated ASCII str() types and unicode()type. 
   Python 3 **has only Unicode (utf-8) string type**.
2. According to [WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) docs, CreateProcess() has an **unicode version** which is defined as CreateProcessW() with the same params.

So if you use Python 2xx, using **CreateProcessA()** . In case of python 3xx, using **CreateProcessW()**.