# kernel32.CreateProcessW: Python crashes after successful launch when trying to access PROCESS_INFORMATION structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

After quite a long time, I'm trying to run some code that explains how debugging works. The book ("Grey Hat Python") is quite old and was written for 32bit systems and Python 2.7.

I'm trying it on Windows 8 64bit with Python 3.4. The process launches successful, but the moment I try to access the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure, Python crashes. I tried it on Windows 7 64bit, it crashes, too.

In Eclipse, I don't get an error message (neither do I get one on my Windows 7 machine, there Python.exe just stops working), but on Windows 8 I do (from within a Powershell):

```
[*] Field 0: ('hProcess', <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>)
[*] Field 1: ('hThread', <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>)
[*] Field 2: ('dwProcessId', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)
[*] Field 3: ('dwThreadId', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    debugger.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
  File "C:\Workspace\my_debugger\my_debugger.py", line 57, in lo
    byref(process_information)):
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Looks like the pointers are pointing nowhere. It stops with the `CreateProcessW()` call!

Within Eclipse:

```
[*] Field 0: ('hProcess', <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>)
[*] Field 1: ('hThread', <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>)
[*] Field 2: ('dwProcessId', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)
[*] Field 3: ('dwThreadId', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)
[*] We have successfully launched the process!
[*] PROCESS_INFORMATION object: <my_debugger_defines.PROCESS_INFORMATION object at  0x00000000031623C8>
```

It stops AFTER the call!

I already applied changes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172093/python-kernel32-createprocessa-what-is-it-doing/22111746#22111746) question to the code below, to no avail.

These are my defines:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

# Let's map the Microsoft types to ctypes for clarity
LPBYTE  = POINTER(BYTE)

# Constants
DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010

# Structures for CreateProcessA() function
class STARTUPINFOW(Structure):
    _fields = [
               ("cb",               DWORD),
               ("lpReserved",       LPWSTR),
               ("lpDesktop",        LPWSTR),
               ("lpTitle",          LPWSTR),
               ("dwX",              DWORD),
               ("dwY",              DWORD),
               ("dwXSize",          DWORD),
               ("dwYSize",          DWORD),
               ("dwXCountChars",    DWORD),
               ("dwYCountChars",    DWORD),
               ("dwFillAtrribute",  DWORD),
               ("dwFlags",          DWORD),
               ("wShowWindow",      WORD),
               ("cbReserved2",      WORD),
               ("lpReserved2",      LPBYTE),
               ("hStdInput",        HANDLE),
               ("hStdOutput",       HANDLE),
               ("hStdError",        HANDLE),
              ]
LPSTARTUPINFOW = POINTER(STARTUPINFOW)


class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields = [
               ("hProcess",         HANDLE),
               ("hThread",          HANDLE),
               ("dwProcessId",      DWORD),
               ("dwThreadId",       DWORD),
              ]
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)
```

And here's the main code:

```
kernel32 = windll.kernel32

class Debugger():

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        pass

    def load(self, path_to_exe):

        # dwCreation flag determines how to create the process
        # set creation_flags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE if you want
        # to see the calculator GUI
        creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS

        # instantiate the structs
        startupinfo         = STARTUPINFOW()
        process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()

        # The following two optiions allow the started process
        # to be shown as a seperate window. This also illustrates
        # how different settings in the STARTUPINFO struct can affect
        # the debuggee.
        startupinfo.dwFlags     = 0x1
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0

        # We then initialize the cb variable in the STARTUPINFO struct
        # which is just the size of the struct itself
        startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)

        print("[*] PROCESS_INFORMATION object: %s" % process_information)
        for count, field in enumerate(process_information._fields):
            print("[*] Field %d: %s" % (count, field))
        if kernel32.CreateProcessW(path_to_exe,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   creation_flags,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   byref(startupinfo),
                                   byref(process_information)):
            print("[*] We have successfully launched the process!")
            print("[*] PROCESS_INFORMATION object: %s" % process_information)
            for count, field in enumerate(process_information._fields):
                print("[*] Field %d: %s" % (count, field))
        else:
            print("[*] Error: 0x%08x." % kernel32.GetLastError())

        print("[*] Debugger finished.")
```

It's simply called by:

```
import my_debugger

debugger = my_debugger.Debugger()

debugger.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe")
```

I admit I'm out of my league here, but you have so start somewhere. As you can see from the output, before `CreateProcessW()`, I can access the struct just fine, but after the
successful launch of the process, the struct appears to be broken.

Why is my `process_information` structure broken?

I fear I'm just blind to spot a typo after looking on that for hours.

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Thank you for reformatting my question more readabble, NorthCat! I'll remember the grey background for the function calls & stuff the next time I ask a question.

Comment: It was the `_fields_` typo. Thank you very much & sorry for that. Can I close this question as just being a typo myself or can a mod please do that for me? It still confuses me though that python from the command line & python from within eclipse stop working at different parts of the code.

Comment: I'll apply your other suggestions to my code as well and will dig more into the documentation to see what each parameter does exactly.

Comment: I don't know about working under Eclipse. Generally in Windows ctypes sets up a structured exception handler before calling a native function. This handles Windows exceptions, an even VC++ exceptions, by raising `OSError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct definitions assign to `_fields` instead of the correct attribute name `_fields_`. To help catch a typo like this, define `__slots__ = '__weakref__'`. This prevents instances from getting a `__dict__`, but it retains the ability to create weak references. Of course, it's still a problem if you have a typo in the `__slots__` definition itself, so a larger project should use a factory function to minimize errors due to typos that pass silently until the process mysteriously crashes.

The metaclass `_ctypes.PyCStructType` adds descriptors for the names in `_fields_` when it creates a `Structure` subclass, so generally an instance has no need of a `dict`. If you accidentally use `_fields` or some other typo in the attribute name, then no descriptors will be added. In this case, accessing a field will raise an `AttributeError`. Using `__slots__` also prevents a typo in a field name from erroneously creating an instance attribute.

```
from ctypes import *

class Good(Structure):
    __slots__ = '__weakref__'
    _fields_ = [('a', c_int), 
                ('b', c_int)]

class Bad(Structure):
    __slots__ = '__weakref__'
    _fields = [('a', c_int), 
               ('b', c_int)]

>>> g = Good()
>>> g.a = 1
>>> g.c = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Good' object has no attribute 'c'

>>> b = Bad()
>>> b.a = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Bad' object has no attribute 'a'
```

---

NB:

- `bInheritHandles` should be `0` instead of `None`. If you had defined `CreateProcessW.argtypes`, then passing `None` would be an `ArgumentError` because `BOOL` is not a pointer.
- `CreationFlags` should include `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`. You're passing `NULL` for `lpEnvironment`, so the new process inherits Python's unicode environment.
- Instead of printing an error code, you can `raise WinError()`. This raises an `OSError` with the formatted error message from `FormatError(GetLastError())`.